# C++ SDL_Rect inside a struct: Does not name a type

Tags: c++, struct, sdl

I am making a basic game and to make things easier I have used:

```
struct entity {
    int health;
    int damage;
    SDL_Rect hitbox;
} player, basicEnemy[10];
```

But when I call:

```
player.hitbox.x = 5;
```

or something similiar, I get the error:

```
'player' does not name a type
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add `typedef` in front of the key word `struct`.

Comment: @Pyro Now `player` is just a type, like `int`. You should use it like this: `player myplayer; myplayer.hitbox.x = 5;`

Comment: @Pyro Maybe some IDE doesn't support variable declaration while define a struct.