# C++ SDL Expected unqualified-id before '-' token

Tags: c++, sdl

I have used:

```
typedef struct entity {
    int health;
    int damage;
    SDL_Rect hitbox;
} player, basicEnemy[10];
```

To handle my player (and enemies). My problem is that I get:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token
```

For this line (and one similiar):

```
if( keystate[SDLK_LEFT] )  player.hitbox.x -= 1;
```

How do I fix this?
If I don't have typedef on the struct the error doesn't occur, but another one does (which is why I made it have typedef)

Headers:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL\SDL.h"
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct entity {
    int health;
    int damage;
    SDL_Rect hitbox;
} playerType, enemyType;
playerType player;
enemyType basicEnemy[10];
```

That solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` defines a type alias. By saying:

```
typedef struct entity {
    // ...
} player, basicEnemy[10];
```

You are saying:

```
struct entity {
    // ...
};

typedef entity player;          // 'player' is an alias for 'entity'.
typedef entity basicEnemy[10];  // 'basicEnemy' is an alias for 'entity[10]'.
```

When what you really mean is to make a `struct` declaration and two instance definitions:

```
struct entity {
    // ...
} player, basicEnemy[10];
```

It may be better to separate them, to avoid this potential confusion:

```
struct entity {
    // ...
};

entity player, basicEnemy[10];
```

Note that a semicolon is required after a `struct` declaration even when it makes no instance definitions.

Comment: But if I remove typedef, then I get this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713013/c-sdl-rect-inside-a-struct-does-not-name-a-type

Comment: @Pyro: The answer to that question is incorrect. But without seeing your actual code, I can’t say what the real issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have some macro (maybe `hitbox`?) being defined unexpectedly in some header file you're including, which is resulting in a syntax error when expanded.

Try running your code through the preprocessor and looking at the preprocessed output.  With GCC and GCC-compatible compilers, this can be done by passing the [`-E` command line flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) instead of `-c`.  For example:

```
g++ myfile.cpp -E -o myfile.ii
```

`.ii` is the recommended file extension for preprocessed C++ files, but it's not required.  Take a look at that file and see what's happening on the line where you're getting the error.

With Visual Studio, you'd instead use the [`/P` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  For other compilers, check your compiler's documentation on how to look at the preprocessed output.

Comment: I don't understand the file's output